# Nodejs, TLS and only allow certain client certificates

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I'm running `NodeJS` with `TLS` and have created a server like so:

```
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem'),

  rejectUnauthorized: true,
  requestCert: true,
  ca: [ fs.readFileSync('clientX-cert.pem') ]
};

const server = tls.createServer(options, (socket) => {
  console.log('server connected', socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
  socket.on('data', function (data) {
    socket.write(data);
  });
});

server.listen(5000);
```

I'm trying to only approve client with a specific client certificate `clientX-cert.pem`, but it seems to fail as my client is getting an `Error: socket hang up` at his end.
When not having `requestCert` it does work, but then everyone is allowed with a TLS certificate.

Have I misunderstood the `rejectUnauthorized: true`, `requestCert: true` and  `ca:`  options?

Comment: Still struggeling with the issue of authenticating against a specific client certificate.

Comment: You will need to provide more details on the TLS handshake that happens for this error. Did you try other clients? Or same client with another server? Can you add more verbosity in your server ?